# How to specify a RouteConfig default route?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

If I'm building a SPA application I just want all URLs that hit my server to go to one controller that will load my index.html and all my javascript for the SPA.

This is because html5mode removes hashes on browsers that support history API.  So if the user were to refresh an html5mode SPA URL then it hits the server...

My solution to this is to just create a "default" route... But I can't find a method that makes this easy in the RouteCollection...

**Update:**
Here's a route that works.  Any better ways to be doing this?  Any reason I shouldn't do this?

```
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{*things}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

Comment: As per my understanding Just reverse it the routes, `Default` should be last

Answer (score 1):

Rather than creating an infinite number of routes you could replace your implementation with a single route definition using a catch-all route parameter, e.g.

```
{something}/{*parameters}
```

Using this catch-all will catch everything from this point on in your URL.

Comment: Thanks Andy, this tip led me to try just {*something} as my catch all which I tested and it seems to be working.